# Deploy a laravel project in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy my laravel project in cpanel, but I get a 505 error. I created a folder in my home directory with all the project files, except the public folder, content of which I put in the public_html. 
I modified the index.php file, to point to the correct files on my main project folder.

```
require __DIR__.'/../myproject/vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myproject/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I am using Laravel 5.4, and since laravel requires php>=5.6.4 I am adding this line to the top of .htacces file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70.php
```

Comment: Your `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70.php` line looks like it's missing a space, for one. Should be something like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php`

Comment: What is the full message on server's log?